# Parsing Array of Strings to Object in Julia

Tags: arrays, string, parsing, julia

I have the following string

```
l = "['name1', 'name2', 'name3']"
```

Now, I'd like to turn this into a proper array of strings, such as:

```
["name1","name2","name3"]
```

I know that one can use `Meta.parse` in Julia, to turn an expression into a Julia object.
The following code works:

```
Meta.parse("['a','b','c']")
```

But when each string has more than one character, Julia gives the following error message:

*Base.Meta.ParseError("character literal contains multiple characters")*

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you're better off with a JSON parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `replace` to change the `'`'s (which are used for chars) into `"`'s (which are used for strings) in the string before parsing it:

```
Meta.parse(replace(l, "'" => '"'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON3` package:

```
julia> JSON3.read(replace("['name1', 'name2', 'name3']", "'"=>"\""))
3-element JSON3.Array{String,Base.CodeUnits{UInt8,String},Array{UInt64,1}}:
 "name1"
 "name2"
 "name3"
```